# How can i convert a to z into a Binary

Tags: java, binary

```
String a = "a";

String b = "b";
String c = "c";
byte[] bytes = a.getBytes(); b.getBytes(); c.getBytes();

StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

for (byte byt : bytes) {
    int val = byt;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
    }
    binary.append(' ');
}

Displaytext.setText(UserInput.getText() + " = " + binary);
```

Comment: If i input thank it will input 1110100 1101000 1100001 1101110 1101011
how ever in my codes it only convert the letter inside the string  it convert only the string a

Comment: In my codes i tried doing string a to c but it just only convert c only but not the a and b

Comment: I tried and it will convert the abc but what if try converting "defg" the "abc" conversion will dislay not the "defg" conversion

Comment: @Hulk It works!!!! thank you .. put your answer so i can up it and check it for you thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to initialize your input-array with the user input:

```
byte[] bytes = UserInput.getText().getBytes();
```

Comment: I can't up it i have a low reputation sorry

Comment: @JavaNewbie no problem - this will change soon enough as you keep learning ;)